# Different profile picture for SO Jobs and Q&A

Tags: bug, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs, profile-picture

Why is my profile picture different between SO Jobs and SO Q&A. Why isn't that the same picture for both profiles? Why can't I upload a new profile picture on SO Jobs and can I only use a gravatar?

Here is my SO Jobs profile:

[image]

And here for SO Q&A porfile:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're different because of the historical split between Careers and Stack Overflow and we never implemented that feature.

There's a similar answer [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/328200/871146), but to quote myself:

> We're also unlikely to implement this because we're pushing towards a release of Developer Story and this feature is already present there.
>
> So, when developer story is released, you'll be able to upload a custom avatar that is different to your regular SO avatar (or you can sync it to your regular SO avatar if you so desire). That avatar will then be used for all employer related actions in SO jobs.
>
> When will it be released? Well, 6 - 8 weeks, naturally.

Comment: You know you've made it when you're quoting yourself...