# Separate Gravatars for Stack Overflow and Jobs

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs

I have seen StackOverflow Jobs only allows users to use Gravatar avatars, however some users, like myself, use different types of avatars depending on the environment.

In StackOverflow Jobs I'd rather use a professional looking picture instead of a forum-ish avatar, since it's a lot more appealing. I'd rather not have a placeholder avatar if I had the chance to use a custom one.

You can understand what I mean by looking at [my CV](https://stackoverflow.com/cv/gfalqui), for instance.

[image]

You can see that my avatar has got a placeholder because I have chosen *not* to use my Gravatar in StackOverflow Jobs.

[image]

What I'd like to have is a file upload where I can decide which avatar to show in the CV, instead of being forced to use Gravatar's one.

Comment: It's easy to do.  Simply alter your email address by adding an + with some extra text to your email address.  An example would be "giampaolofalqui+socareers@gmail.com".  Anything after (and including the) **+** and before **@** in an email address is ignored.  Then, you can go to gravatar and upload a different avatar for that specific email address.

Comment: Isn't that more of a workaround though, instead of a real solution to the problem?

Comment: Agreed, there should be a feature for this. It's a pretty cool workaround though, because even if this gets implemented it won't happen tomorrow. Worth putting as an answer @Will

Comment: I have used the workaround to solve this, however I strongly believe this should be implemented sooner or later.

Comment: They'll get around to it in 6-8 weeks.  I won't answer as it doesn't answer the feature request.

Comment: I don't understand why people is voting to close the question because "it is unclear" even though it appears very clear what's this about.

Comment: @GiamPy I'm pretty sure the culprit is someones cat that jumped on the keyboard while they were trying to reproduce http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306590/2333214

Comment: @Will The `+` is a feature of Google Mail and possible others, is has to be supported by the Mail Provider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We're unlikely to implement this because we're pushing towards a release of [Developer Story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319524/the-developer-story-private-beta-has-started) and this feature is already present there.

So, when developer story is released, you'll be able to upload a custom avatar that is *different* to your regular SO avatar (or you can sync it to your regular SO avatar if you so desire). That avatar will then be used for all employer related actions in SO jobs.

When will it be released? Well, 6 - 8 weeks, naturally.

Comment: Awesome, we're good then.